# Why can't I change my skin in Minecraft Pocket Edition 0.16.0 Beta version?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I was going to play Minecraft PE (Pocket Edition) I saw that I was Alex the female default skin and I went to change it, but then.... IT CRASHED! I tried this over and over again about 160 times just in a few hours and it still won't work! Tons of people had this problem once this update (0.16.0) came but I had it in 0.15.9 and all I did was uninstall Minecraft PE and install it again then restarted my phone and evrything was back.... but now it not doing that.

Answer (score 0):

It actually doesnt fix it if you reinstall.... I myself have this issue and know a handful of other people that experiencing the skin crash bug as well. I currently am trying to find a fix but i know that for me and others, reinstalling will not fix the problem. I would reccomend waiting on mojang to update minecraft, also i suggest to contact support. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I had this issue before and was stuck with the Alex skin. My custom skin was not available. I fixed that by removing a file. That fixed the problem then, but this time around it was different. I had the Steve skin and could not click the "hangar" to change skin....it would just crash. What I did just now is uninstall MCPE , back-up my world folder(zip) then deleted the entire com.mojang folder. I reinstalled game and...PRESTO!!! I have my skin back.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on an android device, do the following:

1. Use a file explorer app (Solid Explorer, FX Explorer, there are plenty around)
2. Navigate to your main storage folder (which is usually what opens by default)
3. Open the folder /games, you will see a folder called com.mojang in there
4. Rename the com.mojang folder to anything else, I used com.mojang.backup for example
5. Ensure that the game isn't running in the background, by clearing it from the currently running history (this is usually a button on your nav bar at the bottom)
6. Start minecraft again, and presto, you'll be able to change your skin again.

If you want to restore your worlds, use the same file explorer and copy the 'minecraft-Worlds' folder from the backup folder to the newly created com.mojang folder. Same goes for resource packs or behavior packs. This folder basically contains all your user-specific minecraft data.

If you look around in it, you'll also find an options file, which stores your specific options. I don't know which file is the culprit for breaking the skin changer, but this approach seems to work every time.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy to do that without uninstalling the app. If you have the MCPE Master app, just download any skin from the app, tap it twice, go back to the Minecraft app, you can see the skin you just downloaded. Tap the hanger button to see if it works. If you don't have the MCPE Master app, just download it and do the steps I mentioned above. I also had this problem too, but when I figured this out it was totally surprising. You also don't have to waste a lot of time to reinstall it again.

Answer (score -2):

Delete it and download it again.

Comment: Hi, welcome to this Stack Exchange community! When answering a question, try to give a response that fully satisfies the question posed. The sort of answer that you're giving, would be much better as a comment.

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't fix it if you uninstall and reinstall it. I've already tried this many times. I recommend waiting until the 1.0 (0.17) update. 0.16.2 doesn't fix it, either. Good luck, I have the same problem. 1.0 is coming out in December.